# Change format of html input element of type datetime

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I am currently developing a mobile web app and I have run into something that bugs me a bit.

I have an Input element of type datetime...

```
<div class="pinkLabel">Date & Time:</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><input data-mini="true" type="datetime" id="OtherClaimDate" /></div>
```

My problem is this. This input seems to have a default format that looks like this...

**2014-01-28T11:55Z**

This format looks a bit bad on the app and I would rather it look someting more like this...

```
**2014-01-28T11:55**
```

or

```
**2014-01-28 11:55**
```

From what I understand reading some other posts the way to go is to use a JQuery plugin and create a mask. Is there another way to accomplish this using javascript possibly ? If not, a short how to on doing this using a JQuery plugin will be much appreciated. But if possible I would prefer a javascript solution.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dt=2014-01-28T11:55;
var ar=dt.split("T");
dt=ar[0]+" "+ar[1];
```

OR

```
var a=dt.replace("T"," ");
```

Comment: Or simply `dt.replace('T',' ');` or `dt.split('T').join(' ')` if you are paid by the metre. :-)

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your answer. It seems I have some coding to do to get everything working, but now I have an idea of what to do.. Feel kind of stupid for not trying something as simple as this.